# Перенаправление с main/фывафыва на main/index.html

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Вообще у меня xampp, проект в папке htdocs/remember, мне нужно, чтобы следующие запросы открывали remember/main/index.html:

```
remember/main/
remember/main/index.html
remember/main/asdfasdf
remember/main/sdf/sdf
remember/main/asdf/asdf/asdf.sdf
```

То есть всё, что после main. Я сделал два варианта:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/remember\/main.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$  /remember/main/index.html
```

и

```
RewriteRule "^remember\/main\/.*$"  "remember/main/index.html"
```

но они не работают. И то и то в .htaccess, RewriteEngine On в начале стоит

Comment: Попробуйте добавить: `Redirect 404 remember/main/index.html`

Comment: Блин, вы просто гений)))) только у меня работает не Redirect, а ErrorDocument

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)